# Prevent Figma auto-nesting

Tags: figma

In Figma, when you drop an object on a frame, it automatically auto-nests.
How do I prevent this?

According to Figma on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/figmadesign/status/1229872874325831680?lang=en) I have to hold the <kbd>space bar</kbd>. But after trying lots of times this doesn't seem to work. Pressing the <kbd>space bar</kbd> before or while dragging an object still puts it in a frame.

I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holding spacebar is correct. I'm using the Desktop version of Figma 97.7 on Mac OS 11.3.1

[image: Pressing nothing, will nest the items]
Pressing nothing, will nest the items

You can see the difference below when holding down spacebar. Watch the layer panel to see the difference between holding spacebar and not holding spacebar when dragging items into frames.

[image: Holding spacebar will prevent nesting]
Holding spacebar will prevent nesting

Comment: Strange, it now seems to work.. maybe I had a bugged version or something

Answer (score 3):

To prevent auto-nesting, hold the spacebar *before* you drag over the frame.

[image]

On a Mac, Safari 14.1

Comment: Came here to learn exact the same trick :) The only thing I'd add is that it's important to first click and hold an element before pressing the Spacebar, and then you can drag it to another place without nesting. Otherwise it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -2):

No other visual editing or design tool treats layers like this. It's not a common convention, it's additive and it should work as such. You shouldn't have told down spacebar for Figma to behave according to convention, instead you should hold down spacebar to enable this new behavior.

Comment: Right, but this is more of a rant than an answer to the question. Check [answer] to learn a bit more about what the site is about.